# Horizontally align some div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I started to learn Bootstrap since few days, and I am facing a problem about horizontal alignment.

In my exemple below, I want to distribute equitably the three divs "first", "second" and "third" on the screen, but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="first"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="second"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="third"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Nevertheless, "justify-content-between" doesn't change anything...

Does anyone could help me?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand once you already used row and `col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4` already 3 times its already horizontal alignment and all equal to each other without saying `justify-content-between ` or maybe you want to achieve something else ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, it is not horizontally align perfectly. I have much more margin on the right than the left, as you can see on this picture: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/19/7/1526170918-bootstraptest.png

Comment: I have provided an full explanation to you down you can check it and let me know if its helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only the `col` class instead of all the other `col-*` classes for the  three columns.

```css
.first,
.second,
.third {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="first"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="second"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="third"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*You should not use fixed height. I have used just to show that the `div`s are aligned at the center.*

## Visit this [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#equal-width) for more info

---

## Update

If the content of the columns are `img` as you have commented that they are, then you should do this:

1. Use only `col-12` and `col-md-4`. `col-12` covers `col-sm-12`. And `col-md-4` covers `col-lg-4` also.
2. For the images, use `img-fluid`, `d-block`, and `mx-auto` classes.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12  col-md-4 ">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/88/Ward_Cunningham_-_Commons-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto">
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 ">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/HNL_Wiki_Wiki_Bus.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto">
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/96/History_Comparison_Example_%28Vector%29.png" class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Check this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QrxagB)

## Update

In order to add space on the left and right side of the images, use `px-5` for the `columns`.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12  col-md-4 px-5">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/88/Ward_Cunningham_-_Commons-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto">
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 px-5">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/HNL_Wiki_Wiki_Bus.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto">
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 px-5">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/96/History_Comparison_Example_%28Vector%29.png" class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Check this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JvZMvG)

if you still need more space, use custom css.

```css
.px-10 {
 padding-left: 120px;
 padding-right: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The "problem" is that the three blocks are supposed to be images, so I would like it to keep the same proportions when the display shrinks...

Comment: @iDrums  Is width of the `img` fixed, for example , `width: 200px` ?

Comment: Thks so much, it's almost perfect ! Last question: how can I have more space between img when they are in column direction ? Thank you !

Comment: No, I didn't fixed any width in CSS

Comment: Thank you so much, your second update solved my problem ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: @mahan why put  height: 500px; I think latest browsers support flex.

Comment: @Lasantha `div`s have `auto` height by default. Since they are empty, they look like a line if you do not do so. Any way, it is just to show that they are aligned at the center.

Comment: @mahan yes, I think better to add min-height, when div is full flex set the height. :)

Answer (score 1):

If your using boostrap 4.1.1
https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

.row is used

```
.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
```

}

so you can just use,

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 first">
            <div class="text-center">
                first 1

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 second">
            <div class="text-center">second<br>second</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 third">
            <div class="text-center">third<br>third<br>third</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Further follow [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Comment: Thank you, it's almost perfect ! But I need space between each div,  not that they be glued together :(

Comment: its simple add extra padding or margin.

Answer (score 0):

what i understood from that image that you sent that mean you already defined width and height for those divs and if you want to center those divs into the `col` you have to use `margin:auto`

[image]

PLEASE open the snippet in a **full page mode** to see it clearly

i just make a snippet to show you 2 cases the first case if you dont use fixed width it will take the col width as you define it here `col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4"` but once you use fixed width then you have to center the div with `margin:auto`

```css
.row {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.first {
  height: 100px;
  /* width: 100px; */
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  height: 100px;
  /* width: 100px; */
  background-color: blue;
}

.third {
  height: 100px;
  /* width: 100px; */
  background-color: green;
}


.first2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
}

.second2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto;
}

.third2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="first"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="second"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="third"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="first2"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="second2"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="third2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="first3"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="second3"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="third3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the time you took to try and solve my problem Adel, but mahan's solution has been the good one :)